# How to detect android device is 64 bit or 32 bit processor?

Tags: android, processor

I'm trying to find a best solution for this question. The reason is the lib in our application can not run with the 64 bit processor so I need to turn it off in this case. 
I found that in Android version 21 (lolipop)and higher we can easily detect that the device is 32 bit or 64 bit processor by using Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS and if It returns the String array with 0 elements then... a hah! The device is 32 bit processor.
How about lower android version? Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS just only support from android Lolipop version and higher.
Thanks & Best Regards,
Wish you guys all the best!

Comment: As I know, 64bit processor only used from Android L and higher. So all before Android version run on 32 bit.

Comment: Are there a lot of (or any) 64 bit devices running KitKat or earlier? Perhaps they could be identified explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: There's no need to check for this on Android versions below Lollipop. That's due the fact that Lollipop introducted platform support for 64-Bit architectures, Android-Versions below Lollipop won't run with a 64-Bit processor.

> Android 5.0 introduces platform support for 64-bit architectures—used
>   by the Nexus 9's NVIDIA Tegra K1. Optimizations provide larger address
>   space and improved performance for certain compute workloads. Apps
>   written in the Java language run as 64-bit apps automatically—no
>   modifications are needed. If your app uses native code, we’ve extended
>   the NDK to support new ABIs for ARM v8, and x86-64, and MIPS-64.
>   [(Source)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html)

Comment: `no modifications are needed` is not always true. Renderscript is not yet supported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=165545

Comment: I strongly disagree. Now, writing Android 11 and 12 on the way, me (and soon many others) have difficulties staying compliant with 32 bit devices including native libraries for their specific purpose. It is soon required to have full 64 bit compliance, so the old trick of removing 64 bit ABIs is no longer a liable option.

Answer (score 9):

```
 try {
            boolean  isArm64 = false;

            BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/cpuinfo"));
            if (localBufferedReader.readLine().contains("aarch64")) {
                isArm64 = true;
            }
            localBufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Or

```
final boolean is64bit = Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS.length > 0;
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using ADB

```
adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep rch
```

**Most outputs:**

Architecture 7 -> **32bit**

Architecture 8 -> **64bit**

> - *this is an extension answer from **@Naval Kishor Jha***
> - *tested in 6 models here*
> - *no root needed*

If you're using JAVA

```
if(Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS.length>0)
  {
  //it's a 64bit
  }
  else
  {
  //it's a 32bit
  }
```

Comment: Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)

Answer (score 4):

Firdt connect the device ato system,
on windows type in the command prompt this command

```
adb shell cat  /proc/cpuinfo | findstr arc
```

on linux or mac base system open terminal and type this command

```
  adb shell cat  /proc/cpuinfo | grep arc
```

if first line of out `contain 32` that mean system type is `32bit`

first line of out if `contain 64` that mean system type is `64bit`

Answer (score 3):

32Bit if below 5.0, because android support 64Bit Until 5.0.
Judge whether Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS support 64 if above 5.0.

```
String bits;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    bits = TextUtils.join(", ", Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS).contains("64") ? "64-Bit" : "32-Bit";
} else {
    bits = "32-Bit";
}
```

You can view a device is 64bit or 32bit by using [Dev Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools).

Answer (score 3):

I found the API, distinguish by app process.

```
Process.is64Bit()
```

Of course, it can be arm 64 or x86-64.

But if you only package arm share library, the x86 device can't install you app.

So the method is work.

If you package x86 share library, then above answer SUPPORTED_ABIS is work.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

- armeabi-v7a -> 32-bit
- arm64-v8a -> 64-bit